# How to change the media player position using Lua generated wiki code?

Tags: lua, wiki, wikipedia

This Lua code:

```
function p.pron_reg(frame)
local cette_page = mw.title.getCurrentTitle()
-- récup des params & valeurs par défaut
local args = frame:getParent().args
local pays = args[1] or '<small>(Région à préciser)</small>'
local text_api = args[2]
local code_lang = args[3] or args["lang"]
local fic_audio = args["audio"]
local title = args["title"] or cette_page.text

-- Génération du wikicode
local txt = pays .. ' : '
if ((text_api) or (fic_audio)) then
    if (fic_audio and fic_audio ~= '') then
        txt = txt .. 'auscultare « ' .. title
        if (text_api) then
            txt = txt .. ' ' .. p.lua_pron(text_api,code_lang,'[]')
        end
        txt = txt .. ' » [[File:' .. fic_audio .. ']]'
    else
        txt = txt .. p.lua_pron(text_api,code_lang,'[]')
    end
else
    txt = txt .. '<small>merci de préciser une prononciation phonétique ou un fichier audio (voir la [[Modèle:écouter|notice]])</small>'
end
return txt
end
```

create an template for IPA and audio pronunciations. Is there any chance to move the audio player next to the IPA pronunciation (before **»**)  just like in the picture ([link](https://static.afbeeldinguploaden.nl/1606/172376/Veu2ntyq.png))

Comment: why don't you do it like it is usually done? '''Germany''' ({{IPAc-en|audio=EN-Germany.ogg|ˈ|dʒ|ɜr|m|ə|n|i}};
There is no line break in the lua code so the positoning of the media player happens somewhere inside the wiki code. I don't think you can change that in the code you provided

Comment: I understand. I will use the english template ([link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:audio-IPA)). But thanks for your answer.

Comment: How it is programming problem at all?

Answer (score 0):

Wikitext generated with Lua code is parsed the same way as wikitext that you just enter yourself, so the problem here doesn't actually have anything to do with Lua. Instead, it has to do with the HTML generated by the wikitext you are outputting. To display the media player inline, you need to use `display: inline-block;` in the CSS. You can do that with the following wikitext without having to edit any of your wiki's CSS files:

```
<div>Foo <div style="display: inline-block">[[File:Example.ogg]]</div></div>
```

If you make your Lua module output something like that, that should do the trick.